# How to Check wether the user input is a 1 digit or more in C?

Tags: c

I want to output the difference between the first time and the second time in hours and minutes(24-hour format). Invalid time input e.g., 25:10 or 18:80 should show "Time format error". Single digit input should show "Time interval: NOT VALID". What I'm trying to do, is to check it in the if condition, if the user input is a 2 digit number, even if the time is for instance, 01:03.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int h1, h2, m1, m2;
    int minuteSum, hours, minutes;
    char c1;
    bool validation = true;
    printf("Enter start time: ");
    scanf("%02d%c%02d", &h1, &c1, &m1);
    if(h1 != "%02d" || m1 != "%02d")
    {
        validation = false;
    }
    printf("Enter end time: ");
    scanf("%02d%c%02d", &h2, &c1, &m2);
    if(h2 != "%02d" || m2 != "%02d")
    {
        validation = false;
    }

    if(h1 >= 0 && h1 < 24 && m1 < 60 && m1 >= 0 && h2 >= 0 && h2 < 24 && m2 < 60 && m2 >= 0 || h1 == 24 && m1 == 0 || h2 == 24 && m2 == 0 || validation == true)
    {
        h1 = h1 * 60 + m1;
        h2 = h2 * 60 + m2;
        if(h1 < h2)
        {
            minuteSum = h2 - h1;
        }
        else if(h2 < h1)
        {
            minuteSum = h1 - h2;
        }
        hours = minuteSum / 60;
        minutes = minuteSum % 60;
        printf("Time interval: %2d:%02d\n", hours, minutes);
    }
    else if(validation == true)
    {
        printf("Time format error.\n");
    }
    else if(validation == false)
    {
        printf("Time interval: NOT VALID");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf()` is a bad choice for this kind of input checks, actually it is a bad choice in nearly all places, due to its limited check capabilities.

`strptime` is not available on all systems.

Instead you can use in example:

- `fgets()` to read the input from the user.
- `strtok()` to separate the read input into fields.
- `sscanf()` to interpret each separated character string as integer; or `atoi()`.

Some notes about your source:

- Raise the warning level of your compiler to the max. Read all warnings and eliminate their causes.
- Use `int main(void)` if you don't use parameters. Omitting `void` is very old style in C, and only correct in C++ and such. In C it means "I don't care about the number of arguments, don't check calling code."
- `printf()` returns a value. If you don't want to use it, show this by `(void)printf(...);`
- `scanf()` returns the number of converted fields. You can use this as a first indicator about the correctness of the input.
- `h1` will receive the converted hour, as you use it later. You can't compare it to a format string.
- Don't write `validation == true` because it is redundant. Name such variables like `isValid` and the source will be more readable. `validation == false` be become `!isValid`.

Answer (score 0):

Please, use `strptime()` to parse date and / or time (or both):

```
struct tm ltm = {0};

char buf1[] = "2011-02-31";
char buf2[] = "10:15";

strptime(buf1, "%Y-%m-%d", &ltm);
strptime(buf2, "%H:%M", &ltm);
```